# can i get imap access using just postfix and mailx?

Tags: centos, email, postfix, smtp, mailx

I have `postfix` and `mailx` installed on a `CentOS 7` server.  I am able to send and receive email from the command line using the `mailx` command.  I am also able to read email in each user's `inbox` using `nano /var/spool/mail/username`.

My impression is that `mailx` and `postfix` only support `smtp`.  The problem is that I am trying to use another `API` (`JavaMail`) to read a user's `inbox`, and all the examples use `imap` or `pop3` protocols.  **Is there a way that I can get `postfix/mailx` to be accessible via `imap`?  Or do I have to also install `dovecot` before I can use `imap` to retrieve `inbox` contents?**

Answer (score 1):

Postfix is an SMTP server (and client, since it does relaying) and local delivery agent (to directories, mailbox files, etc).

mailx is a client for a variety of mail protocols and can access local mail in a variety of storage formats.

But if you want to be able to access your mail with the IMAP protocol (a communication protocol designed specifically for working with remote mailboxes, and which is hard to beat for this purpose) you will need an IMAP server.  You can choose from Dovecot, Cyrus, Courier, or some others.  I've had the best experience with Cyrus, but the configuration is a mess compared to the much easier Dovecot.